# Monitoring /proc/sys/fs/inode-nr

Tags: unix, inode, nagios

As part of a general overhaul of some Nagios scripts, I am adding parameters to the scripts so that the thresholds can be determined on a machine-by-machine basis. As an example, we are specifying percentage of disk free at which to trigger the critical and warning alerts.

One of the scripts monitors `/proc/sys/fs/inode-nr` - this has two values, `nr_inodes` and `nr_free_inodes`. I don't have much understanding of the innards of UNIX, so I'm not quite sure whether it's possible to set a threshold on this file based upon the values within it.

`nr_inodes` and `nr_free_inodes` would suggest that the number of in-use inodes can be calculated as `(nr_inodes - nr_free_inodes)`. Therefore, at a guess, as the number in-use gets closer to X% and Y% of `nr_inodes`, the script should be triggering warning and critical alerts respectively.

Does this seem like a correct kind of assumption to make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting kernel/Documentation/sysctl/fs.txt

> Nr_inodes stands for the number of inodes the system has
>   allocated, this can be slightly more than inode-max because
>   Linux allocates them one pageful at a time.
>
> Nr_free_inodes represents the number of free inodes (?) and
>   preshrink is nonzero when the nr_inodes > inode-max and the
>   system needs to prune the inode list instead of allocating
>   more.

So your assumption is rather incorrect.

You can use "df -i" instead to get inode utilization.

Comment: Thanks, so is there actually any benefit in monitoring /proc/sys/fs/inode-nr ?

Comment: inode-max parameter was removed from kernel?

Comment: @Piotr While inode-nr represents the inodes allocated in memory 'df -i' shows the inodes used on the storage, which is a different thing.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to check disk inode usage (which is actually important for Virtuozzo/OpenVZ installs since we've had issues with that) the check_disk Nagios plugin has -iwarning and -icritical options:

> -W, --iwarning=PERCENT%
>       Exit with WARNING status if less than PERCENT of inode space is free
>
> -K, --icritical=PERCENT%
>       Exit with CRITICAL status if less than PERCENT of inode space is free