# Nagios: Any point in monitoring /proc/sys/fs/inode-nr when also using inode monitoring in check_disk

Tags: monitoring, inode, nagios

We are using the standard Nagios `check_disk` plugin which has [the ability to monitor the inode usage on a system](https://serverfault.com/questions/177379/monitoring-proc-sys-fs-inode-nr/177411#177411).

We also have an in-house plugin which checks the data in `/proc/sys/fs/inode-nr`.

Because the standard Nagios plugin is configured to monitor inode usage, is there any additional benefit in monitoring `/proc/sys/fs/inode-nr` too?

Thanks

Rich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are both effectively monitoring the same thing, I don't see much point in that.